# Appending JSON array to string array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I would like to convert a JSON array to a String array and then append the array of strings to a an array of strings. The JSON array I am dealing with is the following:

```
let allPosts = JSON(value)

//using SwiftyJSON to do something else

// [["0","1","2","3"],["username1","username12","username123","username1234"]]
```

What I've tried so far (I am using SwiftyJSON):

```
let postsIndec =  allPosts[0].arrayValue

//also tried: self.indec.append(contentsOf: postsIndec) //Xcode tells me to remove "contentsOf: "

self.indec.append(postsIndec) // indec being: var indec = [String]()
```

In the last line I get the error `Cannot convert value of type '[JSON]' to expected argument type 'String'` which makes sense but plainly converting it to a string would

I can't loop through it a predefined number of times since the number of strings in a subarray may be greater or less than 4 (used as an example here). Can you help me with this? I couldn't find any questions describing the same problem.

Comment: it is not really clear of what you are trying do ? is that the data that swiftJSON returns `[["0","1","2","3"],["username1","username12","username123","username1234"]]`. Are you trying to extract each array into a separated array such `array1 = ["0","1","2","3"]`

Comment: `allPosts` is a JSON array containing arrays and I want to add the first array of `allPosts` to what is already in the `self.indec` array which contains strings. @Lamar

Comment: I remove my answer because your comment is still not clear, if you say it is string already then do `postsIndec.map { indec.append($0)  }`

Comment: It is not, that's what I'm saying all the time... it's even in the title. I can't do exactly what you just tried to do in the comment since it's JSON and not String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using map to convert [JSON] into [String]:

```
self.indec.append(contentsOf: postsIndec.map {$0.stringValue} )
```

Comment: This causes a similar error :/...: `'map' produces '[T]', not the expected contextual result type 'String'`

Comment: @Moritz updated the answer to append array instead of single element.

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!